# IIS SSL Required on and getting 403

Tags: ssl, iis

Hi there i'v setup a IIS with a SSL cert installed. The IIS is behind a reverse proxy. Im trying to enable SSL Required so a user need a certificate for the authentication.

A user cert is installed in the browser. Its a certificate created by our intern ca.

At the end im getting  "403 - Forbidden".

Its also strange that i do not get any request from the site when i try to access it. I mean the prompt for the cert.

Any clues guys?

Comment: Is it using HTTPS or not? Has it ever worked / does it work without a certificate?

Comment: yes it uses HTTPS. Authentication without "SSL required on" works.

Comment: i'v tried to access the site from intranet and it works with the cert based authentication, seems like its the reverse proxy is the problem which cant handle the authentication.

Comment: You could set up a rewrite from HTTP to HTTPS thus neglecting (redirecting) any non HTTPS traffic to the site. Make sure your binding configuration is right.